# meaning of 振り回す in this context (referred to a person)

Tags: meaning, verbs

Context: summer vacation started and a boy is thinking of asking her crush to spend some time with him, but when he checks his phone he notices that she has not replied to his texts yet. He gets frustrated, wants to write her again but doesn't want to text until she replies. Then he shakes his head after noting the way he's acting and says

あいこに振り回されすぎだ...

After checking in a dictionary,  振り回す means brandish/wield/etc when refered to things, and to manipulate or abuse one's power when referred to a person. But the last 2 definitions don't quite fit here. Could it be something like "controlled"? I'm not sure though. 
Also, is this the "suffering pasive" form? Even though it's not an intransitive verb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically it's close to the latter definition; he thought his behavior was being affected by Aiko too much, as if he were actively controlled. 振り回される can be used like this, even when someone is not intentionally manipulating you. This is not a typical case of "suffering passive" unique to Japanese (English speakers would also use the passive form in this case), but he is "negatively affected", anyway.

Comment: I think a great English equivalent is "jerked around."

Comment: @mamster I think "jerk around" would fit better in the following sentence, wouldn't it?
振り回されて意識せざるを得ないというか